# what does it take to convert theano backend to tensorflow backend with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to convert https://github.com/hexiangnan/neural_collaborative_filtering

The library uses theano as a backend, how involved is it to change to tensorflow backend?
It uses keras as well

I only see `import theano.tensor as T` when I search for `theano` and `import`

Would it be as simple as changing the import statement to tensorflow?

some of import statements that look relavant are:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import keras
from keras import backend as K
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to change the keras backend parameters. This can be done in two ways as described in the [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/#switching-from-one-backend-to-another) one is changing the keras configuration file and the other is changing the environment variable at the top of your script

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'
```

Probably also worth checking if `theano` and `theano.tensor` are used anywhere else, but that should do the trick!